# XML XPath: How to reference an item identified by the attribute value of another item?

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider this XML (part of Adobe Premiere's .prproj files, which are gzipped XML files):

```
<PremiereData> <!-- root object -->
    <Sequence>
        <MarkerOwner>
            <Markers ObjectRef="93"/>
        </MarkerOwner>
    ...
    <Markers ObjectID="93">
```

I like to reach the `Markers` element with ObjectID 93 by following the `ObjectRef` in `Sequence/MarkerOwner/Markers`.

Can I do that with a single Xpath, or do I need to write code that fetches the value of the ObjectRef first, in order to create a second path using that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath should return `Markers` element where `ObjectID` attribute matches `ObjectRef` of `/PremiereData/Sequence/MarkerOwner/Markers` :

```
//Markers[@ObjectID=/PremiereData/Sequence/MarkerOwner/Markers/@ObjectRef]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/3k0aw4cZK)</kbd>**

Notice that `/PremiereData` within the predicate references the root element for it start with `/` (contrast this with `./PremiereData` or just `PremiereData` which will be searching for child of the context element, `Markers`, named `PremiereData`).

Comment: Thanks also for the pointer to the demo evaluator. Had written my own in Pyhthon (and Xojo first, which sometimes crashes), but this website is even nicer.

Comment: Thanks. [I wrote it](https://github.com/har07/XPathEval) in C# and using Saxon as the XML engine :)